# Adding re- to verbs

Tags: grammaire, préfixes

In French I have come across many verbs which have the prefix *re-*, as in English (as far as I am aware) this means the same: *re-*, *back*, etc.

For example:

- *venir* – to come
- ***re**venir* – to come **back**
- *apporter* – to bring
- ***r**apporter* – to bring **back**

Can you simple add this to any verb, for example *jouer* to *rejouer* (to replay)?